# Why does Gembox spreadsheet crash when calling Excelfile.save: FileNotFoundException Could not load file or assembly System.Security.Permissions

Tags: c#, .net-core, gembox-spreadsheet

I am using Gembox to open, modify and save a xlsx file. Calling Save on the Excelfile causes a System.IO.FileNotFoundException.

The problem happens with our company serial key and with the free key.

**Sample Code**

```
using GemBox.Spreadsheet;
namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
            var path = @"C:\code\GemboxTest\App.xlsx"; 
            SpreadsheetInfo.SetLicense("FREE-LIMITED-KEY");
            ExcelFile ef = ExcelFile.Load(path); 
            ExcelWorksheet ws = ef.Worksheets[0]; 
            //ws.Columns[0].Cells[0].Value = 42; 
            ef.Save(path); // <--------------------------------- Crash!
        }
    }
}
```

**Error message**

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Permissions, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
System.Security.Permissions, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
```

**Stacktrace**

```
at   .(Stream , Byte[] , Int32 , Int32 , String )
at   .(Stream )
at   .(Stream )
at   . ()
at   .(Stream )
at    .Dispose()
at   .   ​ (Boolean )
at   .Dispose()
at    .    ​ ()
at    .(Boolean )
at    .Dispose()
at GemBox.Spreadsheet.XlsxSaveOptions.(ExcelFile , Stream ,     )
at GemBox.Spreadsheet.XlsxSaveOptions.Save(ExcelFile excelFile, Stream stream, String path)
at GemBox.Spreadsheet.SaveOptions.(ExcelFile , String )
at GemBox.Spreadsheet.ExcelFile.Save(String path, SaveOptions options)
at GemBox.Spreadsheet.ExcelFile.Save(String path)
at ConsoleApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\code\GemboxTest\ConsoleApp\Program.cs:line 14
```

**Versions**

1. .NET Core 3.1 (also fails with 3.0)
2. GemBox.Spreadsheet Version=45.0.1131
3. Visual Studio 2019 (VisualStudioVersion = 16.0.29905.134)
4. Windows 10 pro 64bit

**Sample csproj file**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="GemBox.Spreadsheet" Version="45.0.1131" />
</ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: This issue no longer occurs in the newer NuGet packages (starting from version `45.0.1148`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the package has a dependency on an assembly that isn't referenced or included.

Typically, a package author would reference their dependencies in their nuspec file for the `Targetframework` (each `TargetFramework`).

---

You can work around it by adding the latest `System.Security.Permissions` nuget package as a dependency to your project.

---

#### Update 1: Additionally

Looking at their example project github repo, I do see references to netcoreapp3.1 there.

I tested both netcoreapp3.1 and netcoreapp3.0, received the dependency package issue with `Save`, worked around it by adding it as a dependency (as this answer suggests). [Gembox.Spreadsheet.Example](https://github.com/GemBox-d-o-o/GemBox.Spreadsheet.Examples/tree/master/C%23)

The example and usage of netcoreapp2.2 had no issues with missing dependencies of the package when attempting a `Save`.

#### Update 2

Removed reference to observed issue with `Load` mentioned in Update 1.  It appears to be unrelated and probably a runtime and\or IDE issue I was experiencing.

Also, this issue was only tested and observed with a console application on windows platform.

Comment: actually, I don't see a netcoreapp3.1 nor netstandard2.1 targetframework support System.Security.Permission NuGet package... does gembox-spreadsheet package actually support netcoreapp3.1?

Comment: Good point. I just tested with .NET Core 3.0 and it causes the same error.

Comment: Basically, it's a bug that you should report to them @nomiso1183.

Answer (score 2):

Here the reply from Gembox support

> Try adding "System.Security.Permissions" package reference to your ".csproj" file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>  
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="GemBox.Spreadsheet" Version="45.0.1131" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Security.Permissions" Version="4.7.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

> As an FYI, I believe that this package is only required for the
>   Console application on Windows. It's not required when you're saving
>   XLSX files with ASP.NET Core application on Windows or when you're
>   saving XLSX files with any .NET Core application on Linux.